# How can I ensure I can login to my laptop with a failing screen?

Tags: ssh, login-screen, vnc, headless, auto-login

I have a Lenovo Flex with Ubuntu installed and the screen has been increasingly unreliable (flickering, sometimes just black). I'd like to ensure I can still use the computer when the screen dies, so I setup ssh and vnc. I'm unable so ssh or VNC into the computer prior to logging in locally, however. This appears to be due to the wifi not being available on the login screen. Is there a way to bypass that? Are there other steps I should be taking to ensure I can use and access the laptop even without a working screen?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using Remote Desktop under the Sharing menu in the Settings. Setup autologin and then you can use either VNC or RDP to access the computer remotely.